# Custom Query with custom post types and category id

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to grab a list of posts by a specific post type and the category id that it is assigned too.

So far from searching online i have managed to come up with

```
function fs_tpl_get_results($post_type, $mycat) {
    global $wpdb;


    $args = wp_parse_args($args,array(
    'post_type'        => '$post_type',
    'term_id'          => 22,
  ));
  extract($args);


    $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  {$wpdb->terms}.*,
  COUNT(*) AS post_count
FROM
  {$wpdb->terms}
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->terms}.term_id={$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id={$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} related_relationship ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID=related_relationship.object_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} related_term_taxonomy ON related_relationship.term_taxonomy_id=related_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} related_terms ON related_term_taxonomy.term_id=related_terms.term_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND (related_term_taxonomy.taxonomy<>{$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy OR related_terms.term_id<>{$wpdb->terms}.term_id)
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type='%s'
  AND related_terms.term_id=%d
GROUP BY
  {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
SQL;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_type,$term_id);



    $results=$wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return $results;
}
```

But it returns an empty result, does anyone have any ideas to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

There are built in wordpress functions that can do this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'your_csategoty_name',
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_posttype'
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    //inside the loop
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post','meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'cat','value' => 'yes','compare' => '%')));









$cat = new WP_Query($args); 







// The Loop

while ( $cat->have_posts() ) : $cat->the_post();





    $P_ID = get_the_ID();



endwhile;



// Reset Post Data

wp_reset_postdata();

$post = wp_get_single_post($P_ID);
```

If it is not working change the page id